# How to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have VBA code for a pivot table to give how many CNs per person from the original table.

I get an error message

> Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class

on the `With ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Type")` line.

Example of table and ideal Pivot Table
[image]

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable

Sheets("Supplier Quality").Activate

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=ws.Range("Table2"))

Set pt = ws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pc, tabledestination:=ws.Range("P1"), TableName:="PivotTable1")
'
With ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Type")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Task Owner2")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Type"), "Sum of Tasks Overdue", xlSum
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. ws.Range("Table2") address is "a2:b28" . So, an error occurs because the range of the field is not included.
2. Other problems arise when you create a pivot table and then apply it to the pivot table again. So it is recommended to apply the refreshPivot code.

---

```
Sub makePivot()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim rngDB As Range
    
    Sheets("Supplier Quality").Activate
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Set rngDB = ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    
    'Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=ws.Range("Table2"))
    Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngDB)
    
    Debug.Print ws.Range("Table2").Address '<~~  A2:B24   first range a2 so error occurs.
    
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pc, tabledestination:=ws.Range("P1"), TableName:="PivotTable1")

    
    
    With ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Type")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Task Owner2")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    'ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Type"), "Sum of Tasks Overdue", xlSum
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Task Owner2")
    With pf
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlCount
        .Caption = "Sum of Tasks Overdue"
    End With
    'pt.AddDataField pf, "Sum of Tasks Overdue", xlCount

End Sub
```

### refresh code

```
Sub refreshPivot()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim rngDB As Range
    
    Sheets("Supplier Quality").Activate
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Set rngDB = ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    
    'Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=ws.Range("Table2"))
    Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngDB)
    
    
    'Set pt = ws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pc, tabledestination:=ws.Range("P1"), TableName:="PivotTable1")
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    With pt
        .ChangePivotCache pc
        .ClearTable '<~~ This must be done.
        .RefreshTable
    End With
    
    With ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Type")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Task Owner2")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Task Owner2")
    With pf
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlCount
        .Caption = "Sum of Tasks Overdue"
    End With

End Sub
```

---